# Create flowchart in R; shapes not changing size or scaling properly

Tags: r, plot, symbols, flowchart

I'm trying to build a flowchart in R, with the following layout:

3 columns or vertical sections:

1. 1st column: Two circles on top of each other with some padding, each
   with an arrows which connect to,
2. 2nd column: One square in the very center of the plot, with two
   arrows extending out which connext to,
3. 3rd column: Two circles on top of each other with some padding.

Each shape should be large enough for two lines of text to fit over it, each line being approximately 8 characters long.

Below is the code I to accomplish this, but the following gaffes appear:

```
# Prepare plot area
plot(0:100, 0:100, type = "n") #axes = F, xlab = NA, ylab = NA)

# Draw shapes
symbols(x = 50, y = 50, squares = 20, add = T) # square in middle
symbols(x = c(15, 15), y = c(70, 30), circles = c(5,5), add = T) # leftmost column of two circles
symbols(x = c(80, 80), y = c(70, 30), circles = c(5,5), add = T) # rightmost column of two circles

# Draw arrows
arrows(x0 = 25, y0 = 75, x1 = 43.5, y1 = 55) # upper-left arrow
arrows(x0 = 25, y0 = 25, x1 = 43.5, y1 = 45) # lower-left arrow

arrows(x0 = 57.5, y0 = 55, x1 = 75, y1 = 75) # upper-right arrow
arrows(x0 = 57.5, y0 = 45, x1 = 75, y1 = 25) # lower-right arrow
```

1. The square and circles won't change size no matter what value I
   put in for their length and radii, respectively.
2. What's more, the circles are all too large.
3. None of the shapes or text scale in size when I shrink the plot,
   but the arrows move just fine.
4. The reason the coordinates for the arrows don't perfectly match
   the length and radii is because then the arrowheads extend into the
   shapes. I want the arrowheads to match exactly where the shapes'
   edges are.

Comment: Maybe you want CRAN package [`diagram`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diagram/index.html). Run `demo("flowchart")` after loading the package and see.

Comment: See also DiagrammeR http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/#features

Comment: Thank you everyone. I've went with `diagram` for now and I'm reverse engineering a solution based on the demo. Will hold onto DiagrammeR for when more sophisticated graphs are needed. I'll aim to post the final code as an answer when it's all done.